# Google Line Chart cast float into integer

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I have a small website that displays among the things a google line chart. Everything is working fine util the moment the value to display is a float, google chart casts it to an integer, although with console.log I can see that the value is really a float.

[image: Preview]

The 37,00 should actually be a 37,50 as it is printed on the console.

Code:

```
function VOLTAGE_chart() {
    var tempo = document.getElementById("janela").value;
    var mysqlData = $.ajax({
        url: "php/voltage_chart.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        data:{},
        success: function(x){
            return x;   
        }
    }).responseJSON;
    if (mysqlData == null){
        alert("Não há dados a apresentar!");
        return;
    }

    var phpDate = mysqlData[0]["time"].split(/[^0-9]/);
    var date = new Date (phpDate[0],phpDate[1]-1,phpDate[2],phpDate[3],phpDate[4],phpDate[5] );

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', 'Voltage'], //{label: 'Time', type: 'date'}, {label: 'Voltage', type: 'number'}
        [date, parseFloat(mysqlData[0]["Voltage"])]
    ]);

    for (i = 1; i < Object.keys(mysqlData).length; i++) { 
        phpDate = mysqlData[i]["time"].split(/[^0-9]/);
        date = new Date (phpDate[0],phpDate[1]-1,phpDate[2],phpDate[3],phpDate[4],phpDate[5] );
        data.addRows([[date,parseInt(mysqlData[i]["Voltage"])]]);
    }
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        fractionDigits: 2,
        decimalSymbol: ','
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    console.log(mysqlData[3]["Voltage"]);
    var startDate = new Date( date );
    startDate.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - tempo);

    var options = {
        title: 'Voltage',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        vAxes: 
        {0: {title: 'Voltage (V)', viewWindow:{min:34, max:45}, gridlines: {count: 12}, ticks: [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45] } },
        hAxes: {0: {title: 'Time', format:'H:m:s', viewWindow: {min: startDate, max: date}  } },
        pointSize: 5
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('VOLTAGE_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The values to display are being pushed from a database using php and Ajax to read the values on the javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the following...

```
for (i = 1; i < Object.keys(mysqlData).length; i++) { 
    phpDate = mysqlData[i]["time"].split(/[^0-9]/);
    date = new Date (phpDate[0],phpDate[1]-1,phpDate[2],phpDate[3],phpDate[4],phpDate[5] );
    data.addRows([[date,parseInt(mysqlData[i]["Voltage"])]]);  //<-- parseInt?
}
```

change to...

```
for (i = 1; i < Object.keys(mysqlData).length; i++) { 
    phpDate = mysqlData[i]["time"].split(/[^0-9]/);
    date = new Date (phpDate[0],phpDate[1]-1,phpDate[2],phpDate[3],phpDate[4],phpDate[5] );
    data.addRows([[date,parseFloat(mysqlData[i]["Voltage"])]]);  //<-- use parseFloat
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much